# Disable View Count on YouTube Video

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to disable the View Counter for a video I upload to YouTube?

I have read several places that this is possible but either the information is old and YouTube has changed or the information was incorrect. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this feature was removed in 2011.

Though it does still seem to show up on their docs:http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2481140

You may have to use the Content Manager: https://cms.youtube.com

Comment: I see. What I was reading was 2011 and before. Thanks!